# passing strings to ctypes functions under Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

```
from ctypes import *
msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = "Hello world!\n"
msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s", message_string)
```

I'm going through a book about Ctypes and Python but the example code just doesn't work.

Could it be because the book was written for python 2 whereas I am on Python 3?

printf is only printing the first letter.

Comment: Please give more information - the actual error message you get, other options you have tried that are working or not working. Also - a better, more descriptive, title will get you more views.

Comment: Maybe. The code works fine for me on Python 2. Have you tried it?

Comment: @dtlussier There is not error message, the OP says that printf does only print the first letter.

Comment: Got it - sorry I missed that in the original post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The C `printf` function is expecting byte strings. In Python 3 all strings are unicode so you'll have to encode to bytes:

```
>>> msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s".encode('ascii'), message_string.encode('ascii'))
Testing: Hello world!
22
```

If you have any non-ascii characters then encode to the relevant windows codepage instead.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I literally couldn't find the answer anywhere. What should I rename the title to make it easier for future users, sir?

Comment: How about 'passing strings to ctypes functions under Python 3.x'?

Comment: I am curious since when encoding to bytes is required as my ex-coworker left a piece of code that (he claimed) was working without encoding.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

bleh, using "".encode('ascii') is ugly. You can often get away with just doing this:

```
TTF_OpenFont(b"assets/droid.ttf", 10)
             ^^
```

Note the 'b' type for the string. This is portable to python 2.7 as well.